# Mysql Order by date

Tags: mysql

This is query where I am trying to fetch data of previous 30 days.

```
    SELECT DAY(calendar.datefield) AS callDay,
    DATE_FORMAT(calendar.datefield,"%d-%m-%Y") AS DataDate,
    COUNT(user_appoint.`id`) AS total_appt,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status_id=6 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS fit,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status_id=7 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS unfit,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status_id=1 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS pending,
    SUM(CASE WHEN status_id=19 THEN 1  ELSE 0 END) AS reexamined
    FROM user_appoint
    RIGHT JOIN calendar ON DATE(user_appoint.`ApptDateTime`) = calendar.`datefield` AND user_appoint.`comp_id` = 123
    WHERE calendar.datefield BETWEEN DATE_SUB(NOW(), INTERVAL 30 DAY) AND NOW()
    # and user_appoint.`comp_id` = 123
    GROUP BY calendar.`datefield`
    ORDER BY datadate ASC
```

The output of the query is as follows:-

```
 callDay  DataDate    total_appt     fit   unfit  pending  reexamined  
-------  ----------  ----------  ------  ------  -------  ------------
 ...
 14  14-01-2016           0       0       0        0             0
 15  15-01-2016           3       0       0        3             0
 16  16-01-2016           0       0       0        0             0
 17  17-01-2016           0       0       0        0             0
 18  18-01-2016           0       0       0        0             0
 20  20-12-2015           0       0       0        0             0
 21  21-12-2015           0       0       0        0             0
 22  22-12-2015           1       1       0        0             0
 23  23-12-2015           0       0       0        0             0
 ...
```

This is giving me data of current month in ascending format and after that the data of previous month in ascending format. I want the data of previous month in ascending format to be and below that data of current month in asc format.

Comment: I always find it a bit hard to read right joins, especially as their ON clause doesn't refer to the *joined* table, but the *other* tables (`AND user_appoint.comp_id = 123` here). I know that many people share this opinion, so you might want to re-write your query to use a left join instead for readability.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are sorting by the string you've created from the date, so you get alphabetic order.

Sort on the date instead:

```
order by calendar.datefield asc;
```